# cassandra inter cluster latency metrics

Tags: cassandra, dse

Is there any mbean for cassandra to get the Cross-data center latency metrics.

I have 6 nodes spread across 2 DC 3 node each. I want to monitor the replication between DCs

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can monitor both overall and DC-specific latencies using the `org.apache.cassandra.metrics` MBean.

**Overall internode latency**

JMX in MBean `org.apache.cassandra.metrics`:

```
type=Messaging,name=CrossNodeLatency
```

**Internode latency for datacenter** with name DC-Name

JMX in MBean `org.apache.cassandra.metrics`:

```
type=Messaging,name=<DC-Name>-Latency
```

You can find these and other useful metrics on this page in the DataStax documentation: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dseplanning/docs/metricsandalerts.html

Comment: I can see metrics for CrossNodeLatency but not able to see for name=<DC-Name>-Latency         ```[root@opcassdrvud01 telegraf]# nodetool sjk mx -b "org.apache.cassandra.metrics:name=ODC_Cloud_prd-Latency,type=Messaging" -mg -f Value
MBean not found: org.apache.cassandra.metrics:name=ODC_Cloud_prd-Latency,type=Messaging
error: nodetool failed, check server logs
``` Do I need to enable it somwhere

Answer (score 1):

To enable org.apache.cassandra.metrics:name=DC-Name-Latency,type=Messaging, you need to add:

```
cross_node_timeout: true
```

to your cassandra.yaml and restart.